# Control visibility by expression (container) not working with array or list values using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a QStringList (part of PostGIS database) that has a multiple choice option where users can select which species have been found. I then need a container displaying follow up questions specific to each species found. I can't seem to find an expression that works for controlling the visibility using values from within a list or array, despite the Preview showing the expression to be functionally working.

An example:

QStringList values: {frog, toad}

First visibility expression I tried:

```
array_contains("species_found",'frog') -> preview = true
```

The container remains hidden when you select frog as an option in species_found

After then testing with a seperate boolean field for each species instead, I found frog_found = true to work (frog_found being the boolean field) as a visibility expression that correctly displays the required container. I noticed the visibility expression returns 1 as a preview so it gave me the idea to instead create the following expression for species_found:

```
if(array_contains("species_found",'frog'),1,0) -> preview = 1
```

The preview returned 1 showing that 'frog' was identified as a result in the list but again the container remained hidden.

I need it to be displayed as a multiple choice list instead of individual check boxes for every option.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just not working as intended?

Comment: You're talking about mapping in the field and creating new features?

Comment: Does "species_found" store an actual array ?, if yes try to set the Control Visibility by Expression field to : array_contains("species_found",'frog')='true' (including the ='true')

Comment: In fact I think your QStringList is recognized as a string rather than as an array. You can try to convert "species_found" to array or you can try a string expression like "species_found" LIKE '%frog%'